# how to hide panel with objects in "form1 design" window?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi every one i need to design an application that shows and hides panel based on the button pressed
example:
button = dashboard ==> show panelDashboard
button = stats ==> show panelStats
those panels overlap like a sandwich .
 is it possible to hide those panel, with their obj,  in the designer window (not in the app) like layers on photoshop?
I tried to be as clear as possible , sorry for my english

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you create a simple picture and add it to your question?

Comment: `those panels overlap like a sandwich` I guess you mean the bread of a sandwich. So just put one on top of the other. Make them have the same Size and same Position. Only the frontmost one will be visible. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @djv  yes i meant that , thank you i tought that it would show me the objects under and on  the panel

Comment: It will only show you the topmost object assuming there is no transparency involved

Comment: @djv and if i have to create a scroll panel how can put object  out of the form, on the panel extended below and out the form?

Comment: you can do that by either dragging it or setting the Location property to something outside the panel's Size.

Comment: @djv yes but i can’t see if the position is correct because the objects are not visible

Comment: I edited my answer with some ways to find a control which has been moved off the form. I hope that helps

Comment: do you mean sendtoback/bringtofront?

Comment: Not sure why they would need to be hidden in the designer, but to make designing easier, set the `.Dock` property of both Panel controls to `Top`, and programmatically hide/show them as needed. This way, they'll be easily accessible in the designer. Also make sure to set the AutoScroll on the form and the Panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the panels to have the same Size and Location values

Here is a form with two panels which don't overlap

[image]

and one where the panels have the same Size and Location

[image]

You can control which panel shows up (on top) with the Document Outline, which can be opened with the key combination

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

See that Panel2 (the Red one) is above Panel1

[image]

and that can be changed by moving Panel1 above Panel2

[image]

Let's say you move a control off the form. This can be achieved either by selecting it and moving it with <kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd>,<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd> or by changing its Location property. If you deselect it, to select it again, you have four options I can readily think of:

1. Tab until you see the outline (if it is within the boundary of the screen), or until the Properties window shows that it is selected.
2. Use the dropdown at the top of the Properties window and click on the control name
3. Use the Document Outline window and click on the control name
4. Drag from the form until you create a rectangle which encompasses the control. This is probably the least reliable option because it's done blindly.

[image]